# How to fill Textbox using dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Please help me.. i have dropdownlist which i have populated from the database table, now i want to fill textbox from the database list...

i have one table

id | juice | rupees

now when i select Mango Juice from juice column from dropdownlist it should show the cost of Mango Juice in textbox by retrieving from rupees column

here is the dropdownlist which is populated from the table

```
<select name="drink" id="drinkid">
<option id="0">-- Select the drink --</option>
<?php
require("dbcon.php");
$getalldrinks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableone");
while($viewalldrinks = mysql_fetch_array($getalldrinks)){
?>
<option id="<?php echo $viewalldrinks['id']; ?>"><?php echo $viewalldrinks['juice'] ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

and here is the textbox

```
<input type="text" name="juicename" id="juiceid" placeholder="Juice">
```

Please help me.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First add `onChange()` event to your `select` tag to call function  `fillTextBox()` every time you change option, then the function will fill the `textbox`:

   ```
   <select name="drink" id="drinkid" onChange="fillTextBox()">
   ```
2. Now you have to get rupees column & store it in every option using `data` attribute :

   ```
   <option data-rupees="<?php echo $viewalldrinks['rupees']; ?>" id="<?php echo $viewalldrinks['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $viewalldrinks['juice'] ?></option>
   ```
3. Create the function `fillTextBox()` that will fill the `textbox` by `rupees` value of selected option :

   ```
   function fillTextBox(){
       var myselect = document.getElementById("drinkid");
       var rupees = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-rupees");

       document.getElementById("juiceid").value = rupees;
   }
   ```

That should do the work, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use javascript to detect changes in your select box, store those values, and then populate the text box with the desired values. You haven't listed a text box in your html, so I'll have to assume that I can access this value using input[type=text]. Here's an approximation of what your javascript should look like given that I am working with incomplete information. Note that your  should probably contain an attribute called value to store your id instead of using the id attribute.

```
var el = document.getElementById('drinkId');
el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var data = {"id": el.value, "text": el.innerHTML};
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')[0].value = data.text;
});
```

You'll need to provide more detail and more of your code if you want an exact solution to your problem.

UPDATE: I see you've added the text box HTML, so here's the updated version of the event handler:

```
var el = document.getElementById('drinkId');
el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var data = {"id": el.value, "text": el.innerHTML};
    document.getElementById('juiceId').value = data.text;
});
```